# Get Created By(not Author) user display name from SharePoint Search REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest, 2019

I need to retrieve information about who added document to SharePoint.

I see that there is field `Author`. But this field may contains several users(information from file metadata will also be included).
[image]

How to retrieve information about who exactly added doc to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Amos,

But I found a simpler solution.

I just added `&selectproperties=CreatedBy` to my URL Query string.

Thank you anyway, your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The created by column's internal name in SharePoint is Author.
The users in Author shoule be the user who create the file and who upload the file to SharePoint.
You could remap the create by column.

1. The XML schema for the Core Results Web Part (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms560074(v=office.12).aspx). NOTE: There are some errors in this MSDN documentation link but there is a community section that lists out the default column in the core results XML
2. The Author and Created By Managed Metadata Properties

The author field is mapped to a number of fields, including the metadata of an office document. When you create an Office document, there is certain information that office captures as “metadata” in the properties section of that document. The Author information is part of this information.

So essentially follow these steps to get a unique name into the Created By Managed property:

1. Map the crawled property (Name: 4; Category: Office (aka Office:4) ) to the CreatedBy Managed property
2. Remove the “ows_created_0x2400e_by” crawled property mapping from the CreatedBy property mapping. This crawled property is a left over from SP 2003 days and is not crawled anymore, except for SP 2003 content.
3. Select the “Select the first property from the property list”. This will ensure that a unique author value is mapped to the “Created By” property (and multiple values are not returned in this property).
4. Make sure to select refinement enabled, so that you can replace the default “Author” refinement filter with the “Created By” refinement filter.
5. Save the CreatedBy Managed property
6. Clear the content collection
7. Reset the index
8. Do a Full Crawl
9. Run a Search, and you will see that the Created By field now contains the most current “Author” information and does not contain a long list of authors

Source:https://blog.tallan.com/2012/07/15/change-the-created-by-metadata-property-to-contain-the-author-information-in-sharepoint-core-search-results/